# Strange spacing above an image placed in anchor tag

Tags: html, css

I have a big banner placed on top of the page just below the top menu and a link is placed on it. Check the below link.

http://dev.shy7lo.com/shoes.html?___store=en&___from_store=arabic

If you check the spacing above the image in firebug or in Chrome Developer Tools, the `a` tag is adding about 17 to 20px extra top space. It is very strange. Can any body suggest why this spacing is there and how to remove it?

Comment: Its because of  `.main-container {
    padding: 30px 30px 0;
} ` you should replce it with `.main-container {
    padding: 0 30px;
}`

Comment: Thanks @Maddy, the issue can be fixed by adjusting the .main-container padding in firefox, but it seems to be still the same in chrome?

Comment: Maddy's suggestion is correct. When de top padding is 0 the space is gone. Contr + F5 your page to be sure

Answer (score 1):

Its because of

```
 .main-container {
   padding: 30px 30px 0;
 }
```

you should replace it with

```
.main-container {
  padding: 0 30px; 
}
```

and make `height:0px` in `#header-search`

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 771px)
#header-search {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: -48px;
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi now define this css and resolve your problem

```
.page-width{
position: relative;
}
#header-search {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -47px;
    width: 25%;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    right: 0;
display: block;  // remove this line
position: relative; // remove this line
float: right;  // remove this line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:none;` from the `.col1-layout .col-main` css.

```
.col1-layout .col-main {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

and put css on `.category-image a`

```
.category-image a {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.